What's the correct translation of "Consecration of the Human Race to the Immaculate Heart of Mary"?
This is for the title of a piece of artwork.
Google Translate came up with "Consecratio Humani Generis ad Immaculatum Cor Mariae".
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Pope Pius XII's eyclical letter Ad Caeli Reginam (1954) includes the following line establishing the feast of the queenship of Mary (festum Mariae Reginae) on May 31 (later moved to August 22):

...Apostolica Nostra Potestate decernimus et instituimus festum Mariae Reginae, quod toto terrarum orbe quotannis die XXXI mensis Mali [sic] est celebrandum. Itemque id iubemus ut eodem die humani generis consecratio Immaculato Cordi Beatae Virginis Mariae iteretur.

My translation:

By our apostolic power we decree and institute the feast of Mary the Queen [=Queenship of Mary], which is to be celebrated throughout the word on the 31st day of May. Likewise we order that on the same day the consecration of the human race to the Immaculate Heart of the Blessed Virgin Mary be renewed.


Just for interests sake who was so important they bumped the Blessed Virgin Mary from May 31 to August 22 - some other queenly eminence? or some potent committee?

@civitas Also the Blessed Virgin Mary? Because it seems May 31 is now the feast of the visitation of the Blessed Virgin Mary. It looks like the changes of 1969 were not universally beloved, though.

Thanks! Wow, long title for my artwork though. What would the translation be for just, "The Immaculate Heart of the Blessed Virgin Mary"? And also, "The Immaculate Heart of Mary"?

@user3502848 "Cor Immaculatum Beatae Virginis Mariae" and "Cor Immaculatum Mariae," respectively

@user3502848 You could, of course, remove "Beatae Virginis" from the bolded Latin from Piux XII to get a literal translation of the English phrase you asked about originally.

"Cor Immaculatum Beatae Virginis Mariae" – I like it! That works for me. Great title!! Thanks!

@user3502848 Don't forget to click the check mark on the answers you think resolve your question to mark that question complete.
